# React: como comparar dos Array y darle valor nulo al que no este incluido?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, javascript-objeto

necesito de sus conocimientos para resolver un problema. Tengo dos array, necesito comparar ambos y a todo aquel numero que no este incluido en el segundo array, darle un valor nulo. me explico:

```
Array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
Array2 = [2,5,7] //Este array puede ir cambiando ya que es un conjunto de checkboxs
```

resultado esperado:

```
[{1:null},2,{3:null},{4:null},5,{6:null},7]
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

AVANCE

logré filtrar los array de la siguiente manera:

```
const filtro = Array1.filter( e => Array2.includes(e)) // devuelve valores que están en ambos arreglos

const filtro = Array1.filter( e => !Array2.includes(e)) // devuelve valores que no están en Array1
```

ahora no se como darle valor null a aquellos que no estén en el primer array.

Comment: y que has intentado, has hecho algo? o esperas que alguien mas lo haga? recuerda que debes subir un [mcve]

Comment: @David081 logré filtrarlo, mi duda ahora es como darle valor null a los números que no se encuentran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí una solución de como puedes hacerlo

```
const Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
const Array2 = [2, 5, 7]; //Este array puede ir cambiando ya que es un conjunto de checkboxs

const newArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Array1.length; i++) {
  if (Array2.includes(Array1[i])) {
    newArr.push(Array1[i]);
  } else {
    newArr.push({
      [Array1[i]]: null,
    });
  }
}
```

newArr tendra el output siguiente:

```
[{1:null},2,{3:null},{4:null},5,{6:null},7]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!